# How many terms of the series 100, 97, 94 have squares less than 200

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many terms of the series 100, 97, 94 have squares less than 200?

So far I tried $(100+(n-1)(-3))^2<200$ and then solving for n but I couldn't get the right answer

Comment: Hint. What is the largest number whose square is less than $200$?

Comment: Note: Title/text mismatch $200 \not= 400$.  Which is the correct value?

Comment: Also, please clarify whether the sequence terminates at $1$, or if it continues below $1$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n^2 < 200$ then $n < \sqrt{200}$.  $\sqrt{200} \approx 14.1$ so for natural numbers, $n^2 < 200$ if $n \le 14$.

So you want $0 \le 100 - 3k \le 14$ so $100 \ge 3k \ge 86$ so $33 \frac 13 k \ge 28 \frac 23$.  So $k$ is an integer $33 \ge k \ge 29$.

So there are $5$ such numbers for $k = 29-34$:  $n = 1, 4, 7, 10, 13$.

Comment: Oh... if the series is infinite and continues past 0 you have $-14 \le n \le 14$ and $-14 \le 100 - 3k \le 14$.  But it's still the same idea.....